# Firedac Firebird master-detail scenario

Tags: delphi, firebird, master-detail, firedac

I have master detail

`CachedUpdates` for the master `true`
`CachedUpdates` for the detail `true`
`DetailCascde` for the detail `true`

The master deals with one record:

```
select * from orders where order_id=:order
```

First I pass -1 as dummy parameter to get an empty master record:

```
orders.Close;
orders.Params[0].AsInteger := -1;
orders.Open;
```

Than I fill the order id with -1 to build the relationship between the master and the detail:

```
orders.Append;
orders.Fields[0].AsInteger := -1;
orders.Post;
```

I insert into the detail successfully with `Append` and `Post`

The problem is in the Firebird database I have this line on before insert trigger for the master

```
new.order_id = coalesce((select max(order_id) from orders) + 1, 1);
```

I ApplyUpdates

```
Orders.ApplyUpdates(-1);
dOrder.ApplyUpdates(-1);
```

So when I ApplyUpdates for the master, the detail won't apply because the master id is altered by the server.

How to solve such scenario?

Comment: You should  **never** use `Select max(some column) +1)` to generate a new pk value, because it will not produce correct results in a multi-user environment.  Use a server-side generator instead - that's what they are there for.

Comment: @MartynA  could you provide more information that's why i use CachedUpdates in fact i migrate DBExpress apps to FireDac to provide multiusers on lan with EventsAlerter...

Comment: Sorry?  Firebird generators are fully described in tthe FB documentation.

Comment: even if i use generators the same problem because id's not showed in user interface if i use generator and make them visible in user interface in case the user cancel the operation due to cachedupdates i lost numbers...

Comment: What's wrong is using a gui to enable a user to cancel out of a new record.  Best practice is to gather all the information for the new record(s) and insert them **before** giving the user the opportunity to edit or delete them.  So, IMO you are avoidably creating a problem for yourself - a user should not be permitted the opportunity to change what they're doing part-way through adding a master-detail.  They should have to make up their mind and get it right beforehand.

Comment: it's master detail with cached updates ! if it was like you said why using cached updated best practices not always suitable.. any way thank's for your comment's

Comment: As Martyn says, don't use `max(some column) +1` to generate ids, it will break down under concurrent execution (depending on the transaction isolation either causing delays or transaction failures, or generated duplicate ids). Use a generator. As to your problem, if you don't want Firebird to override an id, then you should generate it yourself (using a sequence (aka generator)), not in a trigger.

Comment: Lost numbers are not an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591228/primary-key-id-reaching-limit-of-bigint-data-type#16936665