# Sort one column in descending order and retrieve other column in the order it was inserted. MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I've the following table.

```
comment    postid    userid            tempid

c1         199       100003052455644    89
c2         193       100003052455644    2
c4         199       100003052455644    82
c5         198       100003052455644    5
c6         199       1097517748         65
```

Now I wanted to retrieve data in such a way that the data is first ordered in descending according to `postid` column then it is ordered in the order in which rows are inserted.Now when I retrieve the values in which postid is ordered by descending it gives me the result like this.

```
comment    postid    userid            tempid

c6         199       1097517748         65
c4         199       100003052455644    69
c1         199       100003052455644    82
c5         198       100003052455644    5
c2         193       100003052455644    2
```

As you can see the userid who commented the last is appearing at first position.In the `199` postid.I came accross this problem by sorting the `tempid` column in the descending order also.But is there a way that i do not use the tempid column because this table will be filled very quickly and the auto-increment column will fill in quickly so I will be removing this tempid column in the future.So I thought it was not a good idea to do it like this is there any other solution for this ?

Right Now I am using the following query which is giving me the correct result.

```
 SELECT comments.comment,comments.postid,user.name,comments.userid,comments.tempid 
 FROM
  user
   INNER JOIN comments ON user.userid=comments.userid
   INNER JOIN posts ON posts.postID = comments.postid
 WHERE 
 comments.postid <=  
 (SELECT MAX(postid) FROM
   (
     SELECT wall.postid FROM wall,posts WHERE  
     wall.postid = posts.postid AND posts.userid=?
     ORDER BY wall.postid DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
   )sq1
 )

 AND
 comments.postid >= 
 (SELECT MIN(postid) FROM
  (
    SELECT wall.postid FROM wall,posts WHERE
    wall.postid = posts.postid AND posts.userid=?
    ORDER BY wall.postid DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
  )sq2
 ) 

 AND
 posts.userid = ? 
 ORDER BY comments.postid DESC,comments.tempid DESC;
```

Only the last line is of our concern.I want to achive the same result while removing the `comments.tempid DESC` clause . is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to achive the same result while removing the comments.tempid DESC clause . is it possible?

Yes. You could add another column with a timestamp instead of an integer. But it's possible that two rows will have the same timestamp, so it's not a perfect solution.

> But is there a way that i do not use the tempid column because this table will be filled very quickly and the auto-increment column will fill in quickly so I will be removing this tempid column in the future.So I thought it was not a good idea to do it like this is there any other solution for this ?

The autoincrement column can be of type `bigint`. This will be enough for you.

**Related**

- [What if I need a very very big autoincrement ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762327/mysql-what-if-i-need-a-very-very-big-autoincrement-id)

Comment: OK but is there a way to overcome the problem like i needed ??

Comment: @Mj1992: Use bigint instead of int on your autoincrement column. This will solve your problem because it will not fill very quickly. It's unlikely to ever get full in your software's lifetime.